# SD card won't mount despite it working on OSX and otherwise

Tags: sd-card

I have an SD card (used for a Nintendo Switch) on which screenshots are stored. I normally take these to my MacBook to transfer, and it works. However, it does not work on my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop. (Quick note: Another SD card does work, so no fault on the reader.)

As I do hear the sound of something recognized when inserting the card, I did a

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

and I got a rather large printout:

```
Dec  5 19:48:55 Letsnot kernel: [ 1167.879180] mmc0: new ultra high speed SDR104 SDHC card at address 0001
Dec  5 19:48:55 Letsnot kernel: [ 1167.892962] mmcblk0: mmc0:0001 00000 29.8 GiB 
Dec  5 19:48:55 Letsnot kernel: [ 1167.906186]  mmcblk0: p1
Dec  5 19:48:55 Letsnot kernel: [ 1167.981342] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:56 Letsnot kernel: [ 1168.273309] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:56 Letsnot kernel: [ 1168.341340] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:56 Letsnot kernel: [ 1168.343214] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 62518144 flags 80700
Dec  5 19:48:56 Letsnot kernel: [ 1168.397365] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:56 Letsnot kernel: [ 1168.399256] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 62518145 flags 80700
Dec  5 19:48:56 Letsnot kernel: [ 1168.453340] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:56 Letsnot kernel: [ 1168.455256] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 62518146 flags 80700
Dec  5 19:48:56 Letsnot kernel: [ 1168.509336] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:56 Letsnot kernel: [ 1168.511212] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 62518147 flags 80700
Dec  5 19:48:56 Letsnot kernel: [ 1168.565331] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:56 Letsnot kernel: [ 1168.567204] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 62518148 flags 80700
Dec  5 19:48:56 Letsnot kernel: [ 1168.621345] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:56 Letsnot kernel: [ 1168.623221] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 62518149 flags 80700
Dec  5 19:48:56 Letsnot kernel: [ 1168.677329] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:56 Letsnot kernel: [ 1168.679202] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 62518150 flags 80700
Dec  5 19:48:56 Letsnot kernel: [ 1168.733341] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:56 Letsnot kernel: [ 1168.735217] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 62518151 flags 80700
Dec  5 19:48:56 Letsnot kernel: [ 1168.789327] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:56 Letsnot kernel: [ 1168.845332] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:56 Letsnot kernel: [ 1168.901342] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:56 Letsnot kernel: [ 1168.903225] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 62518144 flags 0
Dec  5 19:48:56 Letsnot kernel: [ 1168.957272] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:56 Letsnot kernel: [ 1168.959155] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 62518145 flags 0
Dec  5 19:48:56 Letsnot kernel: [ 1169.013324] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:57 Letsnot kernel: [ 1169.069330] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:57 Letsnot kernel: [ 1169.125336] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:57 Letsnot kernel: [ 1169.181342] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:57 Letsnot kernel: [ 1169.237324] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:57 Letsnot kernel: [ 1169.293344] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:57 Letsnot kernel: [ 1169.295244] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 7814768, async page read
Dec  5 19:48:57 Letsnot kernel: [ 1169.409343] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:57 Letsnot kernel: [ 1169.465323] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:57 Letsnot kernel: [ 1169.521334] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:57 Letsnot kernel: [ 1169.577281] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:57 Letsnot kernel: [ 1169.633317] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:57 Letsnot kernel: [ 1169.689335] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:57 Letsnot kernel: [ 1169.745301] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:57 Letsnot kernel: [ 1169.801328] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:57 Letsnot kernel: [ 1169.857257] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:57 Letsnot kernel: [ 1169.913336] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:57 Letsnot kernel: [ 1169.969234] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:57 Letsnot kernel: [ 1170.025298] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:58 Letsnot kernel: [ 1170.081274] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:58 Letsnot kernel: [ 1170.137301] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:58 Letsnot kernel: [ 1170.193326] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:58 Letsnot kernel: [ 1170.249267] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:58 Letsnot kernel: [ 1170.305321] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:58 Letsnot kernel: [ 1170.361309] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:58 Letsnot kernel: [ 1170.417317] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:58 Letsnot kernel: [ 1170.473315] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Dec  5 19:48:58 Letsnot kernel: [ 1170.475240] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0p1, logical block 7813744, async page read
```

Googling parts of this, all I get is that the SD card is damaged and hopelessly lost. However, it still works perfectly fine on both the Switch and read in my MacBook. So I am genuinely curious why this error appears.

On another note, a newly exfat formatted SD card (also for Nintendo Switch), works fine, so there's no problem with the reader itself.

Comment: The faulty card will eventually cease working on your other systems, too.

Comment: It's not abnormal that an individual card to act like this as it begins to fail.  I had 3 identical micro SD cards, one of which developed a very picky attitude towards the device it was in.  It worked fine in a Samsung S3 but any attempt to use it in a J7 failed, even formatting from the J7 failed.  I can format it in Ubuntu, but any attempt to fill the drive fails.  I eventually junked it, they are cheap now.

Comment: So, can this safely be filed as "Ubuntu discovers a potential flaw in the card, that the other operating systems don't, and thus refuses the card"? Or is there something else amiss?